# Происходит "Ошибка взаимодействия" при нажатии кнопки discord_buttons_plugin

Tags: python, discord.py

После нажатие кнопки происходит "Ошибка взаимодействия"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_buttons_plugin import *
import Key
import discord



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '^')
buttons = ButtonsClient(bot)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Я живой")


@bot.command()
async def crbt(ctx):
    await buttons.send(
        content= 'Нажмите сюда, если хотите создать новый склад',
        channel= ctx.channel.id ,
        components= [
            ActionRow([
                Button(
                    label='Создать',
                    style = ButtonType().Primary,
                    custom_id="button_one"
                )
            ])
        ]
    )


@buttons.click
async def button_one(ctx):
    await ctx.reply("Hello!")

bot.run(Key.config['token'])
```